# How to execute functions in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

How can I execute a function in Postgres?

I tried the following:

```
select pricelimit();
```

But it is giving me error which is as follow:

> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pricelimit(
    p_product_id numeric,
    p_pricelist_version_id numeric)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_Price     numeric;
    v_ProductPrice  numeric;
    bom     record;
BEGIN
    --  Try to get price from PriceList directly
    SELECT  COALESCE (SUM(PriceLimit), 0)
        INTO    v_Price
    FROM    M_PRODUCTPRICE
    WHERE M_PriceList_Version_ID=p_PriceList_Version_ID AND M_Product_ID=p_Product_ID;
    IF (v_Price = 0) THEN
        FOR bom in SELECT bl.M_Product_ID AS M_ProductBOM_ID, 
            CASE WHEN bl.IsQtyPercentage = 'N' THEN bl.QtyBOM ELSE bl.QtyBatch / 100 END AS BomQty , p.IsBOM 
        FROM PP_PRODUCT_BOM b
        INNER JOIN M_PRODUCT p ON (p.M_Product_ID=b.M_Product_ID)
        INNER JOIN PP_PRODUCT_BOMLINE bl ON (bl.PP_Product_BOM_ID=b.PP_Product_BOM_ID)
        WHERE b.M_Product_ID = p_Product_ID
        LOOP
            v_ProductPrice := Bompricelimit (bom.M_ProductBOM_ID, p_PriceList_Version_ID);
            v_Price := v_Price + (bom.BOMQty * v_ProductPrice);
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    --
    RETURN v_Price;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

and function is present in the database
How can I solve this problem please help me

Comment: Show us the function.

Comment: [edit] your question and show us the **complete** `create function` statement (_formatted_ text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: How can i call with parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function requires two parameters but you call it without any.

you need to call it like this:

```
select pricelimit(4, 2);
```

Where `4` is the value for the parameter `p_product_id` and `2` is the value for the parameter `p_pricelist_version_id`

See the manual for more examples and details: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-EXAMPLES

Answer (score 1):

As per definition of your function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pricelimit(
    p_product_id numeric,
    p_pricelist_version_id numeric);
```

function call will be like that

```
select pricelimit(10, 4);
```

You have to pass parameters p_product_id and p_pricelist_version_id.

if you want to pass default values form your parameters, we have to change the function definition as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pricelimit(
    p_product_id numeric default 0::numeric,
    p_pricelist_version_id numeric default 0::numeric)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_Price     numeric;
    v_ProductPrice  numeric;
    bom     record;
BEGIN

    --function Defination
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

then you can call function like this

```
select pricelimit();
```

Hope your doubt is cleared....